# Как правильно загружать данные с backend'a?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

У меня есть небольшая страница на `AngularJS`. Для получения данных с `backend`'а я пользуюсь такой конструкцией:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.0" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script>
            app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myAppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

                $http.get('http://localhost:7080/greeting')
                        .then(function (success){

                        },function (error){

                        });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myAppCtrl">
        {{ 1 + 1 }}
        {{ sum }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Если загрузить данную страницу, то можно увидеть следующую ошибку:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Погуглив, я понял, что данная ошибка возникает из-за обращения из браузера пользователя к стороннему сервису. Но как же тогда происходит обмен `json`'ами между клиенской и серверной стороной ?

Поднимаю `html`-файл через простой запуск правой кнопкой мыши в  `IntelliJ IDEA`. Получается такой `URL`:

`http://localhost:63342/monitoring_gpr/test.html?_ijt=th6t92gm7946kqcuo2bkl4kpkj`

Comment: сервер добавляет нужный заголовок. А как ты запускаешь свой файлик? просто двойным нажатием?

Comment: @Grundy запустил через `IntelliJ IDEA`, но неужели что-то поменяется, если запустить под `nginx` ? А как оформляется такой заголовок ?

Comment: прочитайте про CORS

Comment: @faoxis, важно какой адрес в строке браузера для этой страницы. Добавь его в вопрос. чтобы было видно откуда и куда ты делаешь запросы

Comment: @Grundy добавил

Comment: @faoxis, ага, получается ты серверную часть отдельно запускаешь? которая у тебя по `http://localhost:7080` доступна

Comment: @Grundy Да. Недавно в программирвоании,  хотел проэмулировать общение `backend` с `frontend` через `JSON`.

Comment: @faoxis, ага, для решения задачи нужно чтобы сервер отправлял нужный заголовок. Поэтому стоит добавить код для сервера

Comment: @Grundy Дейтсвительно. К этому запросу надо было всего-лишь добавить `@CrossOrigin` - декоратор (cервер на `Java Spring Boot`).

Comment: @Grundy я вот только не понимаю зачем это нужно... Если любой и так может зайти и получить информацию по этому `URL`, то зачем отдавать отправителю его же адрес ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52070/discussion-between-grundy-and-faoxis).